# Soft question: Which topological properties are transferred by bijective continuous maps?

Tags: general-topology

**Note** The following question was asked by @Tian Vlašić, who then closed it after several interesting comments had been made. I was interested enough that I wanted to revive it.

Let us say that a property $P$ of topological spaces is *transferred by bijective continuous maps*  if for every pair $X,Y$ of topological spaces, the statements $P(X)$ and there exists a bijective continuous map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ implies the statement $P(Y)$.

It is clear that every property of topological spaces that is transferred by bijective continuous maps is a topological property.

I have noticed that the following well-known topological properties are in fact transferred by bijective continuous maps:

- the cardinality of the underlaying set of the topological space
- the cardinality of the topology of the topological space
- Hausdorffness of the topological space

I was quite surprised that Hausdorffness of the topological space is a property of topological spaces transferred by bijective continuous maps (note that this is a stronger statement than the statement that Hausdorffness of the topological space is a topological property).

My question is the following. *What are some other well-known topological properties that are transferred by bijective continuous maps?*

**Note** Some comments  (from F. Shrike) on this question already noted the following:

- Cardinality is pretty trivially transferred
- Compactness and (path-)connectivity are transported (even if you remove injectivity as an assumption). A curious question is whether or not arc-connectivity is transported
- Compactness and connectivity are easy from surjectivity, they have extremely well known proofs (and duplicates on this site). As for arc-connectivity, I have no idea if this is true. It's true if the domain is Hausdorff by a difficult theorem I don't know the proof of + your claim that Hausdorffness is transported.

Comment: The Hausdorff property isn't transferred, is it?  Let $X$ be any Hausdorff space with at least two points, and let $Y$ be the same set with the trivial (indiscrete) topology.  The identity map $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection.  Or have I misunderstood a definition?

Comment: Separability is transferred, first countability is not.

Comment: So if P is to be a transferred property, then for any set $X$ of a given cardinality, one of the following must be true: (1) every topology on X has property P; (2) no topology on X has property P; (3) the trivial topology on X has property P and the discrete topology does not.

Comment: Being "transferred by bijective continuous maps" is equivalent to being "transferred by coarser topologies" in the sense that if property $P$ holds for a topological space $(X,\tau)$, it also holds for $(X,\tau')$ for any coarser topology $\tau' \subseteq \tau$.

Comment: It was good of you to revive this. I'm not sure why Tian deleted it

Comment: On reflection, we should note that Tian was incorrect in claiming that Hausdorffness is transferred (and therefore my comment about arc-connectivity *might* be false); take any non trivial Hausdorff space $(X;\mathcal{T})$ and $\mathrm{Id}:(X;\mathcal{T})\to(X;\text{indiscrete topology})$ which is a continuous bijection

Comment: Thanks, folks, for the revived interest. I'm pleased that others found this dark corner of the subject a worthwhile place to shed a little light.

Comment: Arcwise connectedness (defined as "any two points are connected by an embedded copy of $[0,1]$") does not transfer, since the trivial topology is not arcwise connected (it doesn't contain any embedded copy of $[0,1]$ at all).  See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html

Answer (score 3):

This is merely a partial answer:

While path-connectedness is preserved by such maps, *dis*-connectedness and path-*dis*connectedness are not. If $X$ is the topologist's sine curve
$$
\{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x, \sin(1/x)) \mid 0 < x \le 1\}
$$
then it is path-disconnected. But $f: X \to Y : (x, y) \mapsto x$ is a bijective continuous map, and its image is the unit interval, which is both connected and path connected. Of course, the inverse map is not continuous.

Comment: The topologist's sine curve is connected.  But a simpler counterexample for disconnectedness would be a two-point set with the discrete and the trivial topology.

Comment: D'oh! Of course it is. It's the classic example of "connected but not path-connected." I guess this shows what being a non-mathematician for 25 years will do to your brain. Thanks for correcting this, and for the better example.

Comment: Thanks, FShrike, for editing to remove my error.